# Code Igniter (PHP) SMTP mail not being received

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

I am trying to connect the Email library of Code Igniter to an email account I've created through godaddy. I'm attempting to send the mail via the SMTP Host. As far as I know, all of my information is correct, as the debug mentions that the email is being sent. I'm wondering if I'm missing anything in my SMTP header for it to be correctly received at the recipient's mail server. Here is the debug:

```
hello: 250-p3plsmtpa06-01.prod.phx3.secureserver.net hello [184.168.27.183], secureserver.net
250-HELP
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250-SIZE 31457280
250-PIPELINING
250-8BITMIME
250 OK
from: 250  sender ok
to: 250  recipient ok
data: 354 enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
250 Pdky1o0073x2RKs01 mail accepted for delivery 
quit: 221 p3plsmtpa06-01.prod.phx3.secureserver.net  closing connection
Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: smtp
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Mon, 7 Jul 2014 18:44:58 -0700
From: "Jumpstart Study" <noreply@jumpstartstudy.com>
Return-Path: <noreply@jumpstartstudy.com>
    To: shock_x_trooper@hotmail.com
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?Test_Email?=
Reply-To: "noreply@jumpstartstudy.com" <noreply@jumpstartstudy.com>
X-Sender: noreply@jumpstartstudy.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 2 (High)
Message-ID: <53bb4d1a25b3f@jumpstartstudy.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0


Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_53bb4d1a25b81"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.

--B_ALT_53bb4d1a25b81
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

This is a test message. Please disregard this email.


--B_ALT_53bb4d1a25b81
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html><head></head><body>This is a test message. Please disregard this emai=
l.</body></html>

--B_ALT_53bb4d1a25b81--
```

The `250 sender OK and 250 recipient OK` would tell me that both my emails are valid? And the fact that I'm getting a success message (half way thru the debug) means that the email has been successfully sent. Checking my GoDaddy relays, they are incrementing every time I'm calling my mail function.

Is there anything I'm missing? Is my header incorrect in any way, that would prevent the emails form reaching their destination?

Also, could calling the debug many times in a short period of time ultimately make mail servers interpret the many incoming emails as spam or duplicates, ignoring the subsequent ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you've described, I suspect your email is getting silently filtered at the destination, perhaps your originating ip address is on a default blacklist, or your DNS isn't all set up with matching reverse & forward entries.  You can check your ip address here for starters, http://www.spamhaus.org/lookup/

Although if godaddy's providing the smtp and they're accepting your message for delivery, perhaps it's their address being filtered.

Have you tried sending to other addresses you have control over?

Comment: What do you mean by sending it to other addresses I have control over? Do you mean filter control? I have access to the emails I'm trying to send this too, if that's waht you mean.

Comment: Also checked spamhaus.org, neither my server IP (the one provided by GoDaddy) nor my domain is registered in any blacklist.

Comment: Your subject and Message description contains spam keywords 'Test, Email, disregard, etc..'. Hence obviously, if your godaddy mail provider has mail filter enabled, mail will drop into spam folder. try changing the subject and message content & try sending mail again.

If that doesn't solve problem, also check whether PTR (or) reverse dns record is set for your godaddy mail server. If RDNS/PTR is not set, mail will be sent to default spam on providers like hotmail, outlook, gmail, yahoo, etc..

Comment: by "control over" i meant you are running the incoming email server yourself, not gmail / hotmail / yahoo or other 3rd party that might have filtering you can't see.